Pipewire - Many apps fail to connect to multichannel default audio output
Many apps that go through proton and some native ones don't know how to connect to my multi-channel audio device.

I'm using Pipewire. When I start a steam proton game and set any stereo only output device as the default (for example monitor speakers), all apps connect to it as expected. When I set my actual audio interface as default, I see the app appear in qpwgraph for a split second before disappearing. If I keep the stereo output as default and the app connects, then manually wire the apps output to my interfaces AUX0 and AUX1, the sound works properly.
Is there some way I can create a dummy default audio stereo output that will just always forward the audio to channel 0 and 1 on my interface? I think this way all apps will work and I won't have to deal with it manually every time.
Thanks~
